# TFTP server not listening on port defined

Tags: tftp

I started a tftp server with `atftpd -v --port 69 --bind-address 10.10.10.2 --daemon /srv/tftp/` command, but for some reason I do not see TFTP server listening on port 69 in ss/netstat output. However, if I connect to a TFTP server with TFTP client, I'm able to transfer files and automatically another instance of TFTP server starts(PID 5191):

```
# ss -l -4 -u
Recv-Q Send-Q                                 Local Address:Port                                     Peer Address:Port   
# ss -l -6 -u
Recv-Q Send-Q                                 Local Address:Port                                     Peer Address:Port   
# pgrep -lf tftp
4316 /usr/sbin/atftpd -v --port 69 --bind-address 10.10.10.2 --daemon /srv/tftp/
5191 in.tftpd --tftpd-timeout 300 --retry-timeout 5 --mcast-port 1758 --mcast-addr 239.239.239.0-255 --mcast-ttl 1 --maxthread 100 --verbose=5 /srv/tftp
#
```

`in.tftpd` is a symbolic link to `/usr/sbin/atftpd`. How are clients able to connect to TFTP server if the TFTP server is not listening on UDP port 69? Are there other servers which work in a same manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that the server isn't listening on the port, it's that the tools you're using aren't showing you all of the information you want to see.

You have a couple of options:

Use the `-a` option with `ss` and `netstat` to specify all of the current connections.

```
ss -au
```

Use `lsof -i UDP` to list all of the current UDP connections

```
sudo lsof -i UDP
```

Use `fuser -v -n udp [port]` to determine if the port is currently in use by a process

```
sudo fuser -v -n udp 69
```